# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

Tags: drivers, wireless

i am trying to install wifi driver on HP laptop

sudo modprobe rtl8723de

after this command i got this error

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723de': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

Comment: So let's see what dmesg has to report. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: ~/rtlwifi_new$ dmesg | grep rtl
[   14.500115] rtlwifi: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   14.500155] rtlwifi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   14.724922] phydm_mod: Unknown symbol rtl_get_hal_edca_param (err 0)
[   14.724951] phydm_mod: Unknown symbol _rtl_dbg_trace (err 0)
[   15.154791] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000d lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8723
[   15.154792] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_config.bin
[   15.219530] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723d_fw.bin

Comment: Try a reboot as all the old modules need to be unloaded

Comment: reboot Done.....but nothing happened.

Comment: Still i am not able able to run this      sudo modprobe rtl8723de What should i do now ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you install the driver with sudo make install or with dkms? Please show us: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: sudo dkms status ===> 
                                                                                                                rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414: added
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20190614, 4.18.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.6: added